# REGEX to disallow asterisk (*) in MVC C# application

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application, a user can search for strings but asterisk (*) is not allowed to be in the search string. How do I achieve this using REGEX? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
^[^*]*$
```

Inside a character group, `*` matches a literal `*`. The negated character class `[^*]*` will match 0 or more characters other than an asterisk.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aS1lH6/1)

Comment: Does it work for you? Please let me know if anything is unclear.